# CDKv2 Pipeline produces extra broken references to templates found in nested assembly folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-cdk-typescript

I've created a gist with the full code of this question, found [here](https://gist.github.com/john-heinnickel/9298392810b4d1dfe0209a95bb9a79c9)

I've created a CDK v2 pipeline by following the directions found in the CDK Book (to the best of my ability and with human accuracy).  Every attempt to deploy this (when the fake account references are filled in correctly) has been failing because the synth step is generating an assets manifest that includes additional references to the template files for stacks that are part of each stage I've added to the pipeline.  These same template files actually appear in nested cloud assembly directories and are referenced by their asset files correctly there.

The deployment fails because of the non-existant template files in the cdk.out root directory referenced by Pipeline.assets.json.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have reproduced this both in my original application and with the very stripped down dummy example included in my Gist, the content of which I've also attached to this question below:

cdk.json:

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/create-pipeline.ts",
  "toolkitStackName": "csd-demo-ssm",
  "requireApproval": "never",
  "watch": {
    "include": [
      "**"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "README.md",
      "cdk*.json",
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "**/*.js",
      "tsconfig.json",
      "package*.json",
      "yarn.lock",
      "node_modules",
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/core:bootstrapQualifier": "demo-ssm",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions": [
      "aws",
      "aws-cn"
    ],
    "@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs:arnFormatIncludesClusterName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:disableCloudWatchRole": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:enablePartitionLiterals": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-events:eventsTargetQueueSameAccount": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:standardizedServicePrincipals": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs:disableExplicitDeploymentControllerForCircuitBreaker": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:importedRoleStackSafeDefaultPolicyName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:serverAccessLogsUseBucketPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-route53-patters:useCertificate": true,
    "@aws-cdk/customresources:installLatestAwsSdkDefault": false,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:databaseProxyUniqueResourceName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codedeploy:removeAlarmsFromDeploymentGroup": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:authorizerChangeDeploymentLogicalId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:launchTemplateDefaultUserData": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager:useAttachedSecretResourcePolicyForSecretTargetAttachments": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-redshift:columnId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks:enableEmrServicePolicyV2": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:restrictDefaultSecurityGroup": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:requestValidatorUniqueId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-kms:aliasNameRef": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-autoscaling:generateLaunchTemplateInsteadOfLaunchConfig": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:includePrefixInUniqueNameGeneration": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-opensearchservice:enableOpensearchMultiAzWithStandby": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:newStyleStackSynthesis": true
  }
}
```

bin/create-pipeline.ts:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'
import { CdkPipelineStack } from '../lib/CdkPipelineStack'

const env1: cdk.Environment = { account: '111111111111', region: 'us-east-1' }
const env2: cdk.Environment = { account: '999999999999', region: 'us-east-1' }

const app = new cdk.App({
    defaultStackSynthesizer: new cdk.DefaultStackSynthesizer({
        qualifier: 'demo-ssm',
    bootstrapStackVersionSsmParameter: '/cdk-bootstrap/demo-ssm/version'
    })
})
iam.Role.customizeRoles(app, { preventSynthesis: false })

const pipeline = new CdkPipelineStack(app, 'Pipeline', { ciEnv: env1, devEnv: env1, prodEnv: env2 });

app.synth();
```

lib/CdkPipelineStack.ts:

```
import { Stack, Environment } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

import { ProjectStage } from './ProjectStage'

export class CdkPipelineStack extends Stack {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: CdkPipelineStackProps ) {
        super(scope, id, { env: props.ciEnv });

        const codeSource = CodePipelineSource.connection('john-heinnickel/automation-runbook-demo', 'main', {
            connectionArn: 'arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:123456789012:connection/f1f1f1f1-eeee-5555-aaaa-cdccc0000099',
            codeBuildCloneOutput: true,
            triggerOnPush: true
        });
        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            // we need to activate this for cross account deployments
            pipelineName: 'Pipeline',
            crossAccountKeys: true,
            synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
                // configure source repo here
                input: codeSource,
                // configure installation of dependencies here
                installCommands: ['npm install --frozen-lockfile'],
                // configure build steps here
                commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth'],
            })
        });
    
        const wl1 = pipeline.addStage(
            new ProjectStage(this, 'DevWorkload', { env: props.devEnv }));
        const wl2 = pipeline.addStage(
            new ProjectStage(this, 'ProdWorkload', { env: props.prodEnv }));
    }
}

export interface CdkPipelineStackProps {
    ciEnv: Environment,
    devEnv: Environment,
    prodEnv: Environment
}
```

lib/ProjectStage.ts:

```
import { Stage, StageProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { Construct } from 'constructs'

import { SharedInfraStack } from './SharedInfraStack'
import { StatefulStack } from './StatefulStack'

export class ProjectStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)
        const sharedStack = new SharedInfraStack(this, 'SharedInfraStack');
        const statefulStack = new StatefulStack(this, 'StatefulStack', { vpc: sharedStack.vpc } );
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stack-overflow-gist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "create-pipeline": "bin/create-pipeline.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "@types/node": "20.5.3",
    "aws-cdk": "2.94.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.94.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

lib/StatefulStack.ts

```
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2' 
import * as kms from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-kms' 
import { Size } from 'aws-cdk-lib/core'
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { Construct } from 'constructs'

import { StatefulStackProps } from './StatefulStackProps'

export class StatefulStack extends Stack {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StatefulStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const myVpc = props.vpc

        const nodeRole = new iam.Role(this, 'NodeRole', {
            assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com')
        })
        const nodeInstProf = new iam.InstanceProfile(this, 'NodeInstanceProfile', {
            role: nodeRole
        })
        const secGrp = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SgNode', {
            vpc: myVpc
        })

        const ebsKey = kms.Key.fromLookup(this, 'EbsKey', { aliasName: 'alias/aws/ebs' })
        const dataVolume: ec2.IVolume = new ec2.Volume(this, 'DataVolume', {
            size: Size.gibibytes(50),
            availabilityZone: 'us-east-1c',
            encryptionKey: ebsKey,
            encrypted: true
        })

        // Create the EC2 instance
        const ec2Instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'EC2Instance', {
            vpc: myVpc,
            instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3A, ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM),
            machineImage: new ec2.AmazonLinuxImage({ generation: ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2 }),
            role: nodeRole,
            securityGroup: secGrp,
            requireImdsv2: true,
            detailedMonitoring: true,
            ssmSessionPermissions: true,
            associatePublicIpAddress: false,
            propagateTagsToVolumeOnCreation: true,
        })

        // Attach the data volumes
        dataVolume.grantAttachVolumeByResourceTag(ec2Instance, [ec2Instance]);
        dataVolume.grantDetachVolumeByResourceTag(ec2Instance, [ec2Instance]);
    }
}
```

lib/StatefulStackProps.ts:

```
import { StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { IVpc } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'

export interface StatefulStackProps extends StackProps{
    vpc: IVpc
}
```

lib/SharedInfraStack.ts:

```
// file: lib/shared-infra-stack.ts
import { Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Vpc, SubnetType } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class SharedInfraStack extends Stack {
  public readonly vpc: Vpc;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // assign a VPC to the class property SharedInfraStack
    this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'TheVPC', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      natGateways: 1,
      maxAzs: 3,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          cidrMask: 20,
          name: 'public',
          subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
        {
          cidrMask: 20,
          name: 'application',
          subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        },
        {
          cidrMask: 20,
          name: 'data',
          subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ]
}
```

I started from a project created with `cdk init app --language typescript`.

I followed the CDK Pipelines chapter from ["The" CDK Book](https://www.thecdkbook.com/).

I have stripped this down to the simplest possible thing that could work short of removing the custom qualifier and custom stack names.  I have tried regenerating the cdk.json starting file with the lastest CDK release and updated from 2.93.0 to 2.94.0.  The result has been the same every time.

What I am expecting is for the root Pipeline stack's assets file to not contain references to the stack files that belong to the cloud assemblies for each stage.